# Randomize position of list element in multiple unordered lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple unordered lists with a max of 2 list elements per UL.

My dom structure is somewhat like below:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="question" data-index="0">
    <li class="answer1" data-index="0">
    <li class="answer2" data-index="0">
  </ul> 

  <ul class="question" data-index="1">
    <li class="answer1" data-index="1">
    <li class="answer2" data-index="1">
  </ul> 

  <ul class="question" data-index="2">
    <li class="answer1" data-index="2">
    <li class="answer2" data-index="2">
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need to randomly disperse each li element into random unordered lists. So an li with a data-index of 1 ends up being placed in a ul element with a data-index of 2. What's the best way of accomplishing this with jQuery?

EDIT: I've tried the answer from the other post and all it does is take ever list element and places all of them in each ul. I need a max of (2) list elements per ul, and must be random.

Comment: Take the answer from the other question, understand it and apply it to your situation.

Comment: Try using this [Shuffle DOM](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/shuffle-dom-elements/) function. 

Demo: http://jsbin.com/huruxeye/1/edit?html,js,output